# Cannot get UIActivityIndicatorView to show while loading data

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an UIActivityIndicatorView on a TableViewController. When I start animating in the init I will see the activity indicator, but when I move the start command anywhere else it will not work/show. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong, I cannot seem to find it on here. I want it to show while I am loading data.

TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CategoryTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *cats;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "CategoryTableViewController.h"
#import "NieuwsDataManager.h"
#import "CategoryTableCell.h"
#import "NiewsCategory.h"
#import "NieuwsTableViewController.h"


@implementation CategoryTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        cats = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithArray:[NieuwsDataManager sharedInstance].newsCategories];
        self.title = @"Nieuws" ;
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100,150,120,120)];
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;


        [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];



    NiewsCategory *cat = [[NieuwsDataManager sharedInstance].newsData objectForKey:[cats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



    [[NieuwsDataManager sharedInstance] getNewsByCategory:cat];



    NieuwsTableViewController *nt = [[NieuwsTableViewController alloc] initWithCategory:cat];

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nt animated:YES];

    [nt release];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed in the past that UIActivityIndicators do draw while the UI thread is hung, but it may be possible that you need to perform your task in a background thread in order for the UI thread to animate the progress indicator.  See [Apple's documentation about Concurrency Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).  In general it is good to perform lengthy operations on a background thread so that the UI thread can remain responsive to the user.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

From this code I think it's possible that `tableView` is not as set as the `self.view`. You are adding it in the `view` so it might be possible that your method `[activityIndicator startAnimating];`is actually working, but you have to set it "bring subview to front."  It's possible that it is animated underneath the tableview.

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem, the moment I call startAnimating from the init function it shows normally.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
  //your code
  [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

And i found a tutorial about this, it shows a really nice way to do this:
http://www.markbetz.net/2010/09/30/ios-diary-showing-an-activity-spinner-over-a-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

Is `self.view` already available in init method? Shouldn't such operation performed in `viewDidLoad` method?